# How to unit test forkJoin in Karma

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, karma-jasmine

I have a code which utilizes the forkJoin it goes this way,

```
forkJoin(serviceRequests).subscribe((forkResults) => {
                //Do stuff with forkResults here 
});
```

How do I mock the subscribe so that the code inside can also be evaluated.

I tried various things like following

```
spyOn(Observable, 'forkJoin').and.returnValue(of(mockedResults));
```

Comment: It will may be help you https://github.com/hevans90/ng-test-material/blob/master/rxjs-examples/function-examples.spec.ts#L27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// First I assume you are using forkJoin inside a function like

```
  func() {
    forkJoin(this.getForkedStreams()).pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)).subscribe((streams: any[]) => {
      console.log(streams[0]);
      console.log(streams[1]);
      console.log(streams[2]);

      // logs the array objects provided by the streams
    });
  }
  getForkedStreams() {
    return [
      this.service.func1(),
      this.service.func2(),
      this.service.func3()
    ];
  }
```

// Then in the spec file mock the stream array as

// Mock the service functions like below:

```
     let mockService: any;
    mockService = {
  func1: () => {
    return of({
      prop: 'xyz'
    });
  },
  func2: () => {
    return of({
      prop: 'xyz'
    });
  },
  func3: () => {
    return of({
      prop: 'xyz'
    });
  }
};
```

// Service injection
        new SampleComponent(mockService as any);

```
   /*
Then, in the actual describe => it block, assert against the values mocked up with the variable with which it would be assigned to.
I am not doing that since it is only the mocking that you've asked and you might want to continue from there
*/
```

Comment: it still not evaluating the subscribe on forkJoin